# Compiling SDL on Windows with Mingw gcc

Tags: c, windows, sdl-2

I downloaded SDL for MinGW here : https://www.libsdl.org/download-2.0.php.
But when I try to compile with gcc it can't find the libraries.
It says it cannot find "SDL2/SDL.h".
I tried running GCC with the parameters to include the path after moving the folder containing
SDL2 to the same directory of the project.
I used this command:

```
gcc main.c render.c sprite.c logic.c menu.c level.c -o release -l:SDL2\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libSDL2main.a  -l:SDL2\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libSDL2.a -ISDL2
```

Comment: `-ISDL2` + `#include "SDL2/SDL.h"` means there's a file called `SDL2/SDL2/SDL.h`, is that right? If not, maybe you want `-I.`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the compiler to find the libraries, you need to include the directory it is in using `-I/dir/`